# In Notepad++, removing any text not matching a certain string on each line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have something like:

```
oiuerer jeff oteaweawe
gnwaeeeee jeff nbbaweee
bbbadx  jeff nvxxawee
```

I would like to remove the text which is both before and after the word "jeff" so that each line is only "jeff".  How can I do this with regex?  Thanks

Comment: Use emacs! or vim ( so I don't get murdered ).

Answer (score 4):

Replace `.*jeff.*` with `jeff`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press Ctrl+h to open this dialog.

[image: Replace using Notepad++ regex]